# Dart Multiple Annotations & source_gen

Tags: flutter, dart, annotations, auto-generate

I'm trying to create a package for Flutter that provides source generation using source_gen.  I would like to be able to annotate a class and fields to identify what needs to be generated.  (An example of this would be the libraries Dagger2 or ROOM, for java.)

Given an abstract class:

```
@ServiceCalls("http://www.whocares.com")
abstract class ServiceCalls 
    @Get
    int getCount();
    @Post
    void postCount(int count);
}
```

The following concrete implementation would be generated:

```
class ServiceCallsImp extends ServiceCalls {
    Future<int> getCount() {
        // details for implementing a get service call
    }

    Future<void> postCount(int count) {
        // details for implementing a post call
    }
}
```

So, the big questions I'm trying to answer are:
1) Is an abstract class the way to go, or is a `part` the correct approach?
2) How do I setup `builders` for a 'recursive' annotation processing?  (Annotated fields in an annotated class)

NOTE: I don't really care about service calls, its just an example.